# VSC Source Control View not showing all gitlens tabs in the subview selection menu

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am searching for the tabs "remotes", "branches", "stashes" etc.. within the source control using git, but they are not showing up. I can add repos via terminal, but i still want the interface. What am i doing wrong in my VSC setup?
[VSC Source Control without options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KE80.png)

It should look like this:
[VSC Source control with options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sv2Sl.png)

I have tried reinstalling, and adding and removing extensions back and forth but nothing worked. Suspiciously the tabs have been there 2 Days ago, but now they are gonne.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found a possible solution. I had to uninstall VSC full by doing this:

Windows - Delete `%APPDATA%\Code` and `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode`.
macOS - Delete `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code` and `~/.vscode`.
Linux - Delete `$HOME/.config/Code` and `~/.vscode`

Then install git lens extension again.